# Why hbase even though hdfs is present

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

Why is hadoop using hbase even though hdfs is available for storage?

We can also store table data as blocks in hdfs.

Is the data stored in hbase? If so, then role will hdfs serve?

Answer (score 2):

HDFS is a distributed file system that is well suited for storing large files. It’s designed to support batch processing of data but doesn’t provide fast individual record lookups.

HBase is built on top of HDFS ,actually data gets store on HDFS and is designed to provide access to single rows of data in large tables.

Overall, the differences between HDFS and HBase are

HDFS –

```
Is suited for High Latency operations batch processing
Data is primarily accessed through MapReduce
Is designed for batch processing and hence doesn’t have a concept of random reads/writes
```

HBase –

```
Is built for Low Latency operations
Provides access to single rows from billions of records
Data is accessed through shell commands, Client APIs in Java, REST, Avro or Thrift
```

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop can use HDFS as well as HBase. You need to see difference between filesystem (HDFS) and database (HBase) which offers many features compared to plain filesystem (e. g. random access to the data).

You will need the HDFS running in both cases, bacause HBase is built on top HDFS filesystem.

Comment: u mean data is stored in hdfs(data nodes) using hbase

Comment: Yes, HBase uses HDFS as an underlying (distributed) filesystem.

Comment: does it stored in blocks same as hdfs